# Angular 2: Error when trying to npm start

Tags: angularjs, angular, router

This is the log:

```
node_modules/@angular/router/src/config.d.ts(255,17): error TS1110: Type expected.
node_modules/@angular/router/src/config.d.ts(256,15): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@angular/router/src/config.d.ts(257,16): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@angular/router/src/config.d.ts(258,12): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@angular/router/src/config.d.ts(259,17): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@angular/router/src/config.d.ts(260,19): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@angular/router/src/config.d.ts(261,10): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@angular/router/src/config.d.ts(262,13): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@angular/router/src/config.d.ts(263,14): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@angular/router/src/config.d.ts(264,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
```

Comment: Hi. You should edit your question and add the relevant code that produces those errors. We can't help you if we don't know what you currently have.

Comment: code formatting, title typos fix. Please add your code and the full trace of errors. WIth just this log, we cant help you.

Comment: Since it's coming from angular sources I would guess it's a package configuration problem or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I Had this error after re-install, this steps help for me:

1. replace new version of node_modules folder with the previous version (I saved backup...)
2. run npm start
3. replace previous version of node_modules folder to the new version.

after that npm start work with new version perfectly.
It seems like bug of npm...
I hope this help.